# Activity that pops up before main activity

Tags: android, android-activity

So I have 2 activities, Main Activity and activity with ImageView in it, I need to make 2nd activity(with ImageView) to appear for 2-4 seconds, then disappear and open main activity, a white image with company logo on it. Can someone tell me what exactly should I read in developerandroid to understand how it works and what to do ?) thanks

Comment: Search on __google__ before asked here

Comment: This is a good start to read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: create your second activity add it in manifest and change intent filter launcher to newly created activity

Comment: Before you try any inefficient SplashScreen solution, here's a more efficient way to display an image before the app is loaded: https://antonioleiva.com/branded-launch-screen/

Comment: you want to make a splash screen, Search for splash screen in web, or try this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ND6a4V-xdjI  according to your condition

Comment: thanks) thats just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Please firstly read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966971/what-is-mainfest-file-in-android) it solves all your issues regarding this.

replace manifest code with this

```
            <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>    
            </activity>
```